# Problem related to integration and sine function

Tags: integration

Need help with this integral..how do you simplify the denominator...I need the right approach...one perfect idea can simplify the problem

Evaluation of $$\int\frac{1}{1-\sin x}dx$$

Comment: What integral? I don't see anything sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify the problem by converting a sine into a cosine:
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{1 - \sin x} &= \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{1 - \sin x}\frac{1 + \sin x}{1 + \sin x} =\\[1.5ex]
&= \int\frac{1 + \sin x}{\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx =\\[1.2ex]
&= \int\left(\sec^2 + \sec x\tan x\right)\mathrm dx =\\[1.2ex]
&= \tan x + \sec x + C
\end{align}$$

Comment: It is *highly* recommended that you learn latex if you'd like to provide answers.

Comment: I fixed it for you. Next time please refer to the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Using $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\sin x} = \frac{1}{1-\sin x}\times \frac{1+\sin x}{1+\sin x}$

Answer (score 0):

you can also go with t=tan(x/2)